# How to execute a php script in php script?

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php script inside php script

Here is the code :

```
<?php
echo '<b><?php echo "Hello world";?></b>';
?>
```

When I run the script on my editor, it's returning a blank page.

Is something wrong with my code,why? or is there any better way to run a php script inside php script?

Comment: Just wondering why you would want to do that? I'm not really sure what kind of solution to suggest, because PHP is interpreted at the same time, so the PHP in the string would not be interpreted.

Comment: It's probably better if you tell us what you are trying to do or achieve.

Comment: give your requirements for us to get better idea

Comment: I am creating a php editor, where users will post code, $code variable contains the php code, but it does not echo

**<?php

$code="<?php echo 'hello world?>';
echo $code;?>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval()` function to run any php code which may come as a string. And remember to put closing tag ( `?>`) at the beginning if your code is starting with some `html` (not php code) or if your code itself has an opening tag ( `<?php` ).

```
<?php
$code = '<b><?php echo "Hello world";?></b>'; 
$code = '?>' . $code; //Add a closing tag, because your first texts are not php code.
eval($code); //No need echo again here.
?>
```

> **DISCLAIMER**
>   Executing the dynamic code that may come from user input has a serious security risk. It may do anything to your server. So, make sure, you are not providing this option to any un-authorized person or filter for codes so that only a few type of codes can be executed by this.

Comment: @Starkeen You can accept the answer, if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Use `include` for that:

```
<?php
    include("other.php");
?>
```

**other.php**

```
<?php
    echo "Hello world";
?>
```

↳ http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php